# Перенос body из фрейма в body самой страницы

Tags: javascript, iframe

Глобально объявляю переменную `var Frame=null;`, затем по событию создаю и заполняю его содержимым:

```
Frame = document.createElement("iframe");
Frame.id = "iframe";
Frame.style.width = "30%";
Frame.style.height = "30%";
Frame.src = targetlink;
document.body.appendChild(Frame);
```

В нем пользователь может выполнить какие-то действия и соответственно его содержимое изменится.
В какой-то момент, пользователь наживает кнопку на основной странице и содержимое фрейма должно отобразиться на самой странице, а фрейм закрыться.

Попытка сделать вот так: `document.body = Frame.document.body;` не работает.
Как правильно перенести содержимое фрейма?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<button onclick='drag()'>перенести</button>
```

```js
var Frame = null;

Frame = document.createElement('iframe');
Frame.id = 'iframe';
Frame.style.width = '30%';
Frame.style.height = '30%';
Frame.src = targetlink;
document.body.appendChild(Frame);

function drag() {
    Frame.outerHTML = Frame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
}
```

---

Или можно воспользоваться получением содержимого сайта

```
function drag() {
    getHTML('http://ru.stackoverflow.com', function(html) {
        Frame.outerHTML = html;
    });
}

function getHTML(url, c) {
    request(new XMLHttpRequest());

    function request(xhr) {
        xhr.open('GET', 'https://crossorigin.me/' + url, true);
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                c(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не все сайты дают использовать iframe или переносить к себе. [iframe checker](http://www.tinywebgallery.com/blog/advanced-iframe/free-iframe-checker) в помощь. Проверял на localhost. Стоит понимать, что перенесение содержимого из iframe может повлиять на отсутсвие картинок или других загружаемых элементов из-за ссылок внутри фрейма