# Получение содержимого HTML-страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Как получить всё содержимое HTML-страницы?
Например, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Также [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541385) есть ответ с получением содержимого сайта

Answer (score 0):

Для этих целей используется XMLHttpRequest

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open('GET', 'http://ru.stackoverflow.com', true);  // составить асинхронный (по умолчанию true) GET запрос страницы
  http.onreadystatechange = function () {  // обратная связь: отдаёт ответ на запрос
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {  // отследить момент, когда пришёл полный ответ
      alert( this.responseText );  // this.responseText — ответ в виде текста
    }
  }
  http.send();  // отправить запрос
```

[Подробнее о XHR](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest)

[Подробнее о кросс-доменных запросах](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain)

Comment: Такого оформления xhr я ещё не видел

Comment: @Doofy Вы о чём?

Comment: О костыле сверху. При чём здесь `input`?

Comment: @Doofy прошу прощения, не всё лишнее вырезал

Comment: Во-первых [советы по написанию кода](https://learn.javascript.ru/article/coding-style/code-style.png), во-вторых, перед ответом желательно проверять код на работоспособность. Код работать **не будет**, так как `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: `http.send(null);` ну это уже слишком, `http.send()` будет достаточно

Answer (score -1):

var content = document.body; content - это содержимое страницы

Comment: Что за бред, простите? (минус не мой)

Comment: согласен бред, но это ответ на вопрос... )

Comment: вы уверены что поняли вопрос ?

Comment: а как можно понять вопрос?